# Why does the hot network questions list on academia double spaced while other se sites not?

Tags: discussion, design

Title says it all...

The hot network questions list on [academia](https://academia.stackexchange.com/) shows the hot questions in a double spaced format leaving a lot of room.  Other SE sites the hot questions are one after the other.  Is this status by design?

Comment: To make it look longer, in hopes that no one will notice it's under 2000 words.

Comment: @Shog9 - haha...only for academia - do I get a prize for noticing?  Maybe another comfy t-shirt?  Or a water bottle...now that would be cool...do you guys have waterbottles?

Comment: @JonH don't think so but they have coffee mug, which is HUGE. :)

Comment: @ShadowWizard - I got the coffee mug, Im not much of a drinker but I can always fill it up with H20.  I'd love for a water bottle though...that would be neato!

Comment: I feel like this would be better suited on Meta.Academia, but I'm just a unicorn.